# Get grouped product highest price woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to get grouped products highest price so that i can show only highest price on custom template page.I am using WP_Query to get list of products.

Here is the snippet:

```
                   $series_term = $_GET['series'];
                    $args=array(
                        'series'    => $term_name->slug,
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'posts_per_page' => 8,
                        'filter'    =>$valuecol,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array( 'hidden' ), // Don't display products in the knives category on the shop page
                                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                            )
                        )
                      );

                // $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                 /* Start the Loop */
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
                $feat_prod_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'post-thumb-single');                                 
                $feat_product_img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_query->post->ID) );
                             ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="product-detail">
                            <div class="product-thmbnial">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php $src=$feat_product_img; echo image_product_resize_crop( $src, $w=440, $h=275, $dest = null, $override = false, $createNewIfExists = false ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php  the_title(); ?></a><br/>
                                <span>
                                <?php $wp_product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );  
                                echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></sup><?php 
                            echo $wp_product->get_price();?></span></p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want grouped product highest price to show in place of $wp_product->get_price();

I tried to get children products and but the array is empty.

```
    foreach ( $wp_product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
    $child_prices[] = get_post_meta( $child_id, '_price', true );
}
```

can anyone suggest me how i can get highest price.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.. I tried the same solution earlier but that time it wasn't working.

Here is the fix:

```
 $series_term = $_GET['series'];
                    $args=array(
                        'series'    => $term_name->slug,
                        'post_type' => 'product',
                        'posts_per_page' => 8,
                        'filter'    =>$valuecol,
                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => array( 'hidden' ), // Don't display products in the knives category on the shop page
                                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                            )
                        )
                      );

                // $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                 /* Start the Loop */
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
                $feat_prod_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'post-thumb-single');                                 
                $feat_product_img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_query->post->ID) );
                             ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div class="product-detail">
                            <div class="product-thmbnial">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php $src=$feat_product_img; echo image_product_resize_crop( $src, $w=440, $h=275, $dest = null, $override = false, $createNewIfExists = false ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info"><p><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php  the_title(); ?></a><br/>
                                <span>
                                <?php $wp_product = new WC_Product( get_the_ID() );  
                                $child_prices = array();
                                foreach ( $product->get_children() as $child_id ) {
                                    $child_prices[] = get_post_meta( $child_id, '_price', true );
                                }
                                $child_prices = array_unique( $child_prices );
                                if ( ! empty( $child_prices ) ) {
                                    $min_price = min( $child_prices );
                                    $max_price = max( $child_prices );
                                } else {
                                    $min_price = '';
                                    $max_price = '';
                                }
                                if($min_price == $max_price && !empty($min_price))
                                {
                                    echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></sup><?php
                                    echo $min_price;
                                }
                                elseif(!empty($max_price))
                                {
                                    echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></sup><?php
                                    echo $max_price;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?></sup><?php
                                    echo $wp_product->get_price();
                                }
                            ?></span></p></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```